# Could Laravel Octane be faster than Laravel/Lumen?

Tags: php, laravel, lumen

I was wondering if it could be possible for Laravel to become faster than Laravel/Lumen with the new [Octane package](https://github.com/laravel/octane), which atm. Is still in beta.

But as I can read it seems that Octane will grant Laravel a huge performance boost since it's using a new kind of webserver dedicated to Laravel. Also in regard that it doesn't have to boot up for every single request with Middleware, providers, etc. According to this [article](https://beyondco.de/blog/laravel-octane-introduction)

I can't seem to find any benchmarks, so I'm tempted to do them myself, but I'm hoping someone will do them in the near future.

It would be really nice if that could be the case that it can become faster.

Comment: https://lukecurtis.me/benchmarking-laravel-octane-vs-express-js/